# Cocos2d android Disable touch

Tags: android, cocos2d-android

i want to disable touch in Cocos2d screen. i want touch disable for 4-5 second.any one help me.
thanks

Answer (score 1):

Also you can set a custom timer:

```
static Integer time = 100;
```

and count down when you need it:

```
time--;
...
if (time <= 0) {
    setTouchEnabled = false;
//you can also reset time here: time = 100;
} else {
    setTouchEnabled = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a bool value to toggle your touch code on/off.

```
if (touchEnabled)
{
  // do touch code
}
else
{
  // not …
}
```

Somewhere else, disable touch temporarily:

```
// accept no touches from now on
touchEnabled = false;
```

I leave re-enabling the touches up to you.

Answer (score 0):

Define one time variable

```
static float time;
```

Write below code when you want to disable touch screen

```
this.schedule("touchdiablefor5sec",1f);
```

Now write below method

```
public void touchdiablefor5sec(float dt) {
        //first disable screen touch
        this.setIsTouchEnabled(false);  
        time= time+1;
        //  if 5 second done then enable touch
        if(time==5)
        {
            this.setIsTouchEnabled(true);
            //unschedule the touchdiablefor5sec scheduler
            this.unschedule("touchdiablefor5sec");
        }   
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can disable touch and call a schedule method with time 5 sec as

```
setIsTouchEnabled(false);
schedule("enableTouchAfter5sec",5f);//5f is the duration after that method calls
```

and in enableTouchAfter5sec method enable the touch

```
public void enableTouchAfter5sec(float dt) {
        setIsTouchEnabled(true);  
        unschedule("enableTouchAfter5sec");

    }
```